# How can I use regex to identify the same digit repeated 9 times in SSMS?

Tags: ssms

I'm trying to create a regex statement that would identify 9 of the same repeating digit. I think
    `field like '0^9|1^9|2^9|3^9|4^9|5^9|6^9|7^9|8^9|9^9'`
would work, but is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (for standard reg exp):

```
(\d)\1{8,}
```

`\d` will match any digit (the first one), and `\1` is a backward reference to the match inside the `(...)` and `{8,}` requires 8 more times the backward reference.

**Edit**

I just realize that this question was related to ssms, so you can probably use this:

```
{\d}\1^8
```